# Proving that if $|r| \lt 1$ and $p \in \mathbb Z^+$ then $n^pr^n$ converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Theorem :  If $|r| \lt 1$ and $p \in \mathbb Z^+$ then $n^pr^n$ converges to $0$  .

We want to prove this theorem in some specific steps.

1. Show that its enough to consider the case in which $0 \lt r \lt 1$. ( Which is so obvious and i have no problem in this step.)
2. Assume that $n,k$ are two natural number such that $n \gt 2k$. Prove that ${ n \choose k } \gt \frac{n^k}{2^k k!}$.
3. Select a positive number like $a$ such that $1+a=\frac{1}{r}$ and explain that why $\forall n\gt2p+2$ we have
   $\frac{1}{r^n} \gt \frac{n^{p+1}}{2^{p+1}(p+1)!}a^{p+1}$ .
4. Prove that for each large enough $n$, $n^pr^n \lt \frac{2^{p+1}(p+1)!}{na^{p+1}}$ and complete the proof of the theorem.

I have no idea how to prove steps $2$ to $4$.
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdot\dotsc \cdot (n-k+1)}{k!}$. Use the binomial formula. Combine.

Comment: @DanielFischer Which part of the proof are u talking about ? :)

Comment: Steps 2, 3, and 4. But I made a mistake for step 3 initially.

Comment: @DanielFischer well, i thought but i didn't get what u meant ... what should i combine ?

Comment: @DanielFischer can you please explain your idea? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For step 2, use

$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot \dotsc \cdot (n-k+1)}{k!}$$

and note that for $n \geqslant 2k$, each of the $k$ factors in the numerator is $> \frac{n}{2}$.

In step 3, by the binomial formula

$$\frac{1}{r^n} = (1+a)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k \geqslant \binom{n}{m} a^m$$

for every fixed $0 \leqslant m \leqslant n$, since $a > 0$. Choose an appropriate $m$, and combine the resulting inequality with the result of step 2. Finally, cross-multiply to arrive at the inequality of step 4. Use the fact that $\frac{2^{p+1}(p+1)!}{a^{p+1}}$ is a constant independent of $n$ to reach the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

2) Write out $\binom{n}{k}$ and multiply by $2^n k!$ and $(n-k)!$ to get:

$2^n n\cdot(n-1)\cdot...\cdot(n-k+1) > n^k$

and $2^n n\cdot(n-1)\cdot...\cdot(n-k+1) = 2^n \prod^k_{j=1}(n-k+j) >  \prod^k_{j=1}2(n-k+j)$

Now since $n>2k$ every factor is bigger than $n$ and therefore the expression is bigger than $n^k$.